# Preg Match for Letters in Arabic and Numbers in English

Tags: php, sql, regex

I want to allow my users to enter such record - Letters in Arabic and Numbers in english. (عسا871)

And I run a preg match on the top, I tried it this way -

```
if(!empty($_POST['number']))
    if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]|[\p{Arabic}]+$/',$_POST["number"]))
        die("Number Data Modification");
```

It still does not accept Arabic, what is a right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^[0-9]|[\p{Arabic}]+$` regex accepts strings that have 1 ASCII digit at the start of string (`^[0-9]`) or (`|`) Arabic letters at the end (`[\p{Arabic}]+`).

Most probably you want to allow any string consisting of either ASCII digits or Arabic letters:

```
'/^[0-9\p{Arabic}]+$/u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQFhxC/1)